# How to connect Google Data Studio to AWS Athena?

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena, looker-studio

I need to connect [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/) to [AWS Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/).  One way to do that is with a [the JDBC URL connection option](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343).  I used the following parameters in [the Database Authentication](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/datasources/create?connectorId=8) form and  I got the error shown below:

Params:

**Url**

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443;UID=[MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY];PWD=[MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY];S3OutputLocation=s3://[S3_OUTPUT_BUCKET];
```

**Username**

```
[MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY]
```

**Password**

```
[MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY]
```

**Error:**

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Any solution to connect Google Data Studio to AWS Athena or even connect to AWS S3 should solve this problem.  I tried [this Google Apps script](https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script) to connect to S3 but failed to connect with authentication error as shown in [this open issue](https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script/issues/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Data Studio does not appear to support installing drivers (not that surprising, since it's a hosted, not self-hosted, app).

I think your best bet would be to create a connector -- I actually am surprised no open-source community connector exists yet. I think basically you'd need to wrap the Athena API, following the [Google Data Studio connector guide.](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference) It's not simple, but it looks doable...

Answer (score 5):

An open-source connector for Google Data Studio now exists [here](https://github.com/canyousayyes/datastudio-aws-athena-connector).

To use it, you need to follow the instructions detailed [here](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/deploy.md), i.e. copy/paste the code into a Google Apps Script Project and then deploy it to Google Data Studio.

Comment: I think that this should be the accepted answer